# Получить содержимое веб-страницы

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Уже в истерике мучаюсь второй день, я новичок в js так-что извините за глупые вопросы.

**Суть в том, что мне нужно получить содержимое веб страницы в виде текста.
Пример:**
geturl(https://quickfounder.ga/example_1.json);
Возвращаемый ответ:

```
{
    "fruit": "Apple",
    "size": "Large",
    "color": "Red"
}
```

Уже перемучался с этими jquery, что раньше работало, уже не работает и устарело. Проще говоря мне нужен аналог php - file_get_contents

Заранее спасибо

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Первая же ссылка по запросу "fetch codepen": https://codepen.io/astrotim/pen/vGgmXr

Comment: @Владимир Гончар, к сожалению это не то, там идет поиск определенных элементов и экранирование их с помощью li. А мне нужен вывод всей страницы

Answer (score 0):

```js
const getPageHtml = async (url) => {
    try {
    return await fetch(url, { method: 'GET' });
  } catch(e) {
      console.log(e);
  }
};

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", async () => {
    const root = document.getElementById('root');
    root.innerHtml = await getPageHtml('https://quickfounder.ga/example_1.json');
});
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Типа такого, но сервер должен отправлять заголовок 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
В общем, из браузерного js вызвать аналог file_get_contents не получится

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Почему-то не работает у меня ваш ответ. А как насчет импорта результата из php файла?

Comment: Я же и говорю, что сервер должен отправылять 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'. Тот сервер с которого вы пытаетесь что-то прочесть не отправляет такой заголовок. 
Что вы имеете в виду под импортом результата из php файла? Можно делать запрос на php файл, который хранится у вас на сервере, а в нем уже file_get_contents

Comment: спасибо за ответ, да, я это и имел введу.